# JSoup not parsing entire HTML from file

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a system that creates reports in HTML. I'm attempting to add data to the report but I am having issues when parsing / writing out the document:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "ISO-8859-1");
BufferedWriter htmlWriterTEST = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\TEST.html"), "UTF-8"));
htmlWriterTEST.write(doc.toString());
htmlWriterTEST.flush();
htmlWriterTEST.close();
```

The output just stops halfway through a table. I've been looking at other questions and I know you can specify `maxBodySize` when using the `connect` method (although the HTML files I'm using are only 44KB) but how can you set this when parsing from file?

What else could be causing the truncated output?

[Input HTML](https://github.com/dendleberry/trackIT/blob/master/HTML_SAMPLE)

** Sorry guys, made a bit of a schoolboy error. Didn't flush my writers! Thanks for your help

Comment: Which version of Jsoup do you use? I'm using 1.8.1 and it works fine.

Comment: Make sure you are closing your output writers. Also post more code, maybe I can see where the problem is.

Comment: please post sample input so we can duplicate the problem, at least the table that triggers the problem, which might be enough.

Comment: @philwalk, there is a link to the HTML being used in the question already.

Comment: @TDG I'm using version 1.8.3.

Comment: @JonasCz Yes, that's why. Forgot to flush my writers. Doh!